# Running R via terminal in Windows and leaving R session open

Tags: r, windows, console, rscript

Suppose that I have a R script called `test.R`, stored at `C:\`, with the following content:

```
x <- "Hello Stackoverflowers"
print(x)
```

To run it via terminal one could simply call:

```
Rscript C:\test.R
```

And as expected, the result will be:

[image]

However, what I wonder is whether there is a way to run `test.R` via Windows console but after that staying within the executed R session instead of closing and going back to the console cursor? That is, staying inside the R session instead of going back, in the image above, to `C:\R\R-3.4.1\bin>`.

For instance, when compiling Python code with `python.exe` I can easily accomplish a similar thing by passing the `-i` parameter to the `python.exe`call.

How could I do that with R?

Comment: What is the purpose ? Why not open a session and call the script instead?

Comment: @cderv because I am automatizing calls to R scripts via other software.

Comment: you should not need to have the R session still open after the rscript call though. I am not sure to understand why you want that. Your current solution is of to call R scripts from other software

Comment: @cderv I am implementing a simple R IDE within my application. Also, this is required for many more usages, like for instance to have a R console inside Sublime, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your .Rprofile:

```
STARTUP_FILE <- Sys.getenv("STARTUP_FILE")
if (file.exsts(STARTUP_FILE)) source(STARTUP_FILE)
```

and then set the indicated environment variable outside of R and then run R. e.g. from the Windows cmd line:

```
set STARTUP_FILE=C:\test.R
R
... R session ...
q()
```

**Variations**

There are many variations of this.  For example, we could make a copy of the .Rprofile file in a specific directory such as ~/test, say, and add this code to that copy

```
source("~/test/test.R")
```

in which case R would only run test.R if R were started in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with that solution, though, is that it will require such modifications for every file. I should have specified that I needed it to work without doing that. I will update the question with more details about my usage case.

Comment: Not so.  Just set the environment variable and then start R or write a simple batch file to do it. e.g. `(set STARTUP_FILE=C:\test.R) && R` or if your batch file is called myR.bat then run `myR C:\test.R`