# R scripts not executalbe in Windows 10

Tags: r, windows, shell

I try to open an R script in Windows 10 (double clicking on it), the R shell opens and states:

> ARGUMENT 'C:\ [Path to my R script]\filename.R' __ignored__
>
> Plus all the information about my R version

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to avoid it?
Thanks for your help!

Running R 3.4.2, Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Try to use `source( )` function from the R-shell or R-studio. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Ekatef Thanks, that seems to work!I actually want to make this work from another program but maybe I can use this functionality

Comment: It was recently a discussion about running R-scripts from another program https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894892/running-r-via-terminal-in-windows-and-leaving-r-session-open. Probably, it'll be helpful for you